# js value of html input multidimensional array

Tags: javascript

i had this input in my html

```
<input name="accessoires[123][]" min="0" max="99" type="number" value="0">

<input name="accessoires[456][]" min="0" max="99" type="number" value="0">

<input name="accessoires[789][]" min="0" max="99" type="number" value="0">
```

in javascript i want to get the value of the multidimensional  array
i tried

```
var accessoires = $("input[name*='accessoires']")
        .map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
```

but i get only the value of the input, not the $AccessoiresItemId

how is it possible in javascript, to get multidimensional array values?

Comment: `return [this.name, this.value];` to return the name and value in a nested array.

Comment: like this? `var accessoires = $("input[name*='accessoires']")
        .map(function(){return[this.name, this.value];`

Comment: If this is a single input, for what reason are you expecting 'multi-dimensional' values? If there are more than one of these inputs, then your code works as it is: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/m675v3se/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It doesn't work because they want to get the name corresponding to each value, not just the values.

Comment: @Supptech Yes. Just replace `return $(this).val()` with `return [this.name, this.value];`.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that. Although `return [this.name, this.value]` would return the full name, not the `$AccessoiresItemId` which OP seems to require.

Comment: Yeah, its return the name, but i only need the value of `$AccessoiresItemId` its it possible to get the value as array key? i use the js result to push it with ajax to php.

Comment: How are the index values set in the HTML? Assuming it's some backend code doing it, then the simple solution would be to put those values in a data attribute, eg `data-foo="123"` then read that data attribute back out again in your `map()` handler. This avoids the need to have any ugly (and brittle) string manipulation code.